# how can I use " for loop" to calculate p(2) p(3) p(4) p(5) and after that print them at the same time?

Tags: r

How can I use the loop to calculate p(2) p(3) p(4) p(5), and after that print them at the same time?

```
A<-matrix(c(0.75,0.25,0,0.25,0,0.75,0,0.75,0.25) , nrow = 3)
p0=t(matrix(c(0,0,1) , nrow = 1))
p1=t(A) %*% p0
```

Question:

```
p2=t(A) % * % p1,p3=t(A) % * % p2,p4=t(A) % * % p3,p5=t(A) % * % p4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea:

```
A <- matrix(c(0.75,0.25,0,0.25,0,0.75,0,0.75,0.25) , nrow = 3)
p0 = t(matrix(c(0,0,1) , nrow = 1))

p = matrix(ncol = 6, nrow = 3)
p[,1] = p0

for (i in 2:6){
  p[,i] = t(A) %*% p[,i-1]
}

colnames(p) = paste0("p", 0:5)
p
#output:
     p0   p1     p2       p3        p4        p5
[1,]  0 0.00 0.1875 0.187500 0.2695312 0.2695312
[2,]  0 0.75 0.1875 0.515625 0.2695312 0.4130859
[3,]  1 0.25 0.6250 0.296875 0.4609375 0.3173828
```